# How can I track the add ons(products) associated with the transaction data layer- GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have following data layer deployed on confirmation page which captures the transactional data all correct.
    enter code here

```
<!-- Enhanced Ecommerce Data Layer through Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': rtCONFIRMATIONNUMBER_0,            
        'revenue': rtTOTALCOST,        
        'tax':rtTAX_0,
      },
      'products': [{                           
        'name': rtPROPERTYNAME+'-'+rtROOMTYPE_0,    
        'id': rtCONFIRMATIONNUMBER_0,
        'price': rtTOTALCOST,
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
},{
    'event': 'purchase'
});
</script>
<!-- END Enhanced Ecommerce Data Layer through Google Tag Manager -->
```

But this is not enough when user is adding some other add ons available at the time of checkout which I want to capture under the same transaction ID.
How can I modify this to capture the added Items data?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about add-ons here..... Usually you should fire this after the confirmation, when the transaction is really complete.

Comment: Add-ons meaning: Lets say I am selling an iPhone with accessories. So main Product is iPhone and USB cable, charging doc, Ear buds, etc can be add-ons. All of them should reflect in reports under one transaction ID in Product performance report. If the transaction has taken place with add-ons.

Comment: So these are just more products.... You need to fire the purchase action after the transaction is complete and the user added or not "add-ons" to their trasnaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there looks to be an error with your `dataLayer.push`. Your `event` key should be defined in the same object as your `ecommerce` object if you are planning on firing tags with the `purchase` event:

```
dataLayer.push({
   'ecommerce': {
      // ecommerce stuff
   },
   'event': 'purchase'
})
```

Back to your main question now, one option would be to add the other add-ons as separate products:

```
 dataLayer.push({
   'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
         'actionField': {
            'id': rtCONFIRMATIONNUMBER_0,
            'revenue': rtTOTALCOST,
            'tax': rtTAX_0,
         },
         'products': [{
               'name': rtPROPERTYNAME + '-' + rtROOMTYPE_0,
               'id': rtCONFIRMATIONNUMBER_0,
               'price': rtTOTALCOST,
               'quantity': 1
            },
            {
               'name': rtPROPERTYNAME2 + '-' + rtROOMTYPE2_0,
               'id': rtCONFIRMATIONNUMBER2_0,
               'price': rtTOTALCOST2,
               'quantity': 1,
               'category': 'add-on'
            },
            // other product objects like add-ons
         ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: Nyuen - First, Thank you for taking time to advice me on this.

1. As you said "event key (purchase) should be defined in the same object as ecommerce. I will make the changes to existing script. If it looks to be an error, any possibility. Still it was able to pass on the correct values to gtm on purchase event.


2. If I add other add-ons as separate products based on the data layer above. Is it going to capture all the add-ons (lets say customer added 4 add -ons) associated with the purchase?

Comment: Yes the add-ons will be captured as long as that one is its own product object and you have set them apart as add-ons (eg. With the category). Always test before you publish.

Comment: Thanks Much! I will try this one and see what happens.